# How to calculate $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}C_n^kk^m$?

Tags: combinatorics

I tried to calculate

$ F(m)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}C_n^k k^m,$

where $m=0,1,\cdots,m$, $C_n^k$ is the binomial coefficient $\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

It's obvious when $k$ is $1,2,3$ by Binomial theorem and differentiation.

e.g. $F(2)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}C_n^k k^2 x^{k-1}|_{x=1}=(x\cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k} C_n^k k x^{k-1})'|_{k=1}=(x\cdot(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}C_n^k x^k)')'|_{k=1}=(x\cdot((x-1)^n)')'|_{x=1}=(nx(x-1)^{n-1})'|_{x=1}=[n(x-1)^{n-1}+n(n-1)x(x-1)^{n-2}]|_{x=1}=0.$

And repeat this method then I got

$F(m)=0, 0\leqslant m\leqslant n-1.$

I guess that $F(n)=n!$ because when calculating the general $F(m),m<n$ the last term equals to $\dfrac{n!}{(n-m)!}x^{m-1}(x-1)^{n-m}$. So when $m=n$, the other terms have the factor of $(x-1)$, let $x=1$ then they all equal to 0 except the last one. Let $m=n$, it follows that $F(n)=n!$.

**But I'm not sure if my proof is rigorous. And I can not calculate the general $F(m)$ directly.**

Comment: I think it is correct!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955339/a-property-of-every-real-polynomial/1955598#1955598

Answer (score 1):

We can show the identity with the help of generating functions. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
  [z^m]e^{kz}=[z^m]\left(1+kz+\frac{(kz)^2}{2!}+\cdots\right)=\frac{k^m}{m!}\tag{1}
  \end{align*}

> We obtain for integers $0\leq m\leq n$
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}k^m}&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}m![z^m]e^{kz}\tag{2}\\
> &=m![z^m]\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(e^z\right)^k(-1)^{n-k}\tag{3}\\
> &=m![z^m]\left(e^z-1\right)^n\tag{4}\\
> &=m![z^m]\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots\right)^n\tag{5}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\begin{cases}
> n!\qquad& n=m\\
> 0\qquad& 0\leq m<n
> \end{cases}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the *coefficient of* operator as shown in (1).
- In (3) we do a small rearrangement.
- In (4) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (5) we see the smallest power of $z$ is $n$.