# An extrapolation problem: finding the constant term of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

$f(x)$ is a degree $6$ polynomial and $f(n)=\frac{1}{n}$ when $n=1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$.
 How to find the constant term of $f(x)$?

Comment: Consider $xf(x)-1$.

Comment: Still can't get it :(

Comment: @StanleyLeung What are the values of $xf(x)-1$ at $x=1,2,3,4,5,6$ and $7$?

Comment: The values are 0. But I can't get the constant term from it...

Comment: A non-constant complex polynomial of degree $n$ has exactly $n$ roots counting with multiplicity. ([Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra))

Comment: You know seven zeros of a seventh degree polynomial. Surely you can write the general seventh degree polynomial in a form which reflects this fact?

Comment: However it is a sixth degree polynomial...

Comment: Which polynomial is degree $6$, and which polynomial do we know the roots of? (Hint: those are not the same.)

Comment: We know the roots of xf(x)-1.

Comment: xf(x)-1=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)(x-7)

Comment: @StanleyLeung Not quite; set $x=0$ in your equation.

Comment: f(0)=constant term...
f(0)=(-5040+1)/0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [the well-known properties of the forward difference operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1955598/44121),
 if $f$ is a polynomial with degree $\leq 6$ we have
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{7}\binom{7}{k}(-1)^k\,f(r+k) = 0 $$
for any $r\in\mathbb{R}$. In our case, by picking $r=0$ and exploiting the binomial theorem we get
$$ f(0)=\sum_{k=1}^{7}\binom{7}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-(1-x)^7}{x}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^7-1}{x-1}\,dx=H_7=\color{red}{\frac{363}{140}}.$$
The approach suggested by Lord Shark the Unknown in the comments leads to
$$ f(0)=\left.\frac{d}{dx}(x-1)\cdots(x-7)\right|_{x=0}\stackrel{\text{LogDerivative}}{=} H_7$$
the same outcome, which is not surprising.

Comment: Is (n k) representing nCk?

Comment: @StanleyLeung: I would say the opposite, nCk is usually denoted as $\binom{n}{k}$. And $\sum_{k=1}^{7}\binom{7}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$ is just $H_7$, the seventh harmonic number.

Comment: Not terribly happy with this question (and hence the answers), but I'm not going to make an issue of it, because it is clear the asker participated in the comments below the question.  Note the asker's second question is no better, in terms of its standing as a PSQ. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515247/inequality-of-abba

Answer (score 4):

Leading questions: What degree is $xf(x)-1$? Since we know seven of its roots, what form must it have? What constant term could $xf(x)-1$ possibly have (i.e. what is its value at $x=0$)? Therefore, what polynomial must it be? Now what is $f(x)$?

Comment: The constant term of xf(x)-1 is -5040

Comment: @StamleyLeung What is the value of $xf(x)-1$ at $x=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Write
 $$f(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{3}x^{3}+a_{4}x^{4}+a_{5}x^{5}+a_{6}x^{6}$$

Now form a system of equations:

$$1=f(1)=a_{0}+a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}+a_{5}+a_{6}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}=f(2)
=a_{0}+a_{1}2+a_{2}2^{2}+a_{3}2^{3}+a_{4}2^{4}+a_{5}2^{5}+a_{6}2^{6}$$

$$\frac{1}{3}=f(3)
=a_{0}+a_{1}3+a_{2}3^{2}+a_{3}3^{3}+a_{4}3^{4}+a_{5}3^{5}+a_{6}3^{6}$$

$$\frac{1}{4}=f(4)
=a_{0}+a_{1}4+a_{2}4^{2}+a_{3}4^{3}+a_{4}4^{4}+a_{5}4^{5}+a_{6}4^{6}$$

$$\frac{1}{5}=f(5)
=a_{0}+a_{1}5+a_{2}5^{2}+a_{3}5^{3}+a_{4}5^{4}+a_{5}5^{5}+a_{6}5^{6}$$

$$\frac{1}{6}=f(6)
=a_{0}+a_{1}6+a_{2}6^{2}+a_{3}6^{3}+a_{4}6^{4}+a_{5}6^{5}+a_{6}6^{6}$$

$$\frac{1}{7}=f(7)
=a_{0}+a_{1}7+a_{2}7^{2}+a_{3}7^{3}+a_{4}7^{4}+a_{5}7^{5}+a_{6}7^{6}$$

Now you have a linear system of equations and you know that the **Vandermonde matrix** is invertible in this case, so the solution is unique. Then use **Cramer rule** to find $a_0,\ldots,a_6$.